# Complex annotation in Django 1.8

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-1.8

From https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/conditional-expressions/ and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/ I can see that I can do more complex annotation with Django 1.8.

Normally I would use

```
return qs.extra(select={
  my_sum: "
    SELECT SUM(price)
    FROM some_table_name
    WHERE group_id IN (
      SELECT m2.id
      FROM other_table_name m2
      WHERE m2.some_field_name = 'some value'
    )
  "})
```

Will this be possible with the additional features in the Django ORM?

Comment: wow, these are awesome

Comment: Nice to see the Django ORM borrowing some features from `sqlalchemy.sql`.

Answer (score 0):

The above is possible and is covered in the [Django Documentation on Conditional Aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-aggregation).

In the example, they show the model of

```
from django.db import models

class Client(models.Model):
    REGULAR = 'R'
    GOLD = 'G'
    PLATINUM = 'P'
    ACCOUNT_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (REGULAR, 'Regular'),
        (GOLD, 'Gold'),
        (PLATINUM, 'Platinum'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    registered_on = models.DateField()
    account_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=1,
        choices=ACCOUNT_TYPE_CHOICES,
        default=REGULAR,
    )
```

and then perform an aggregation on it:

```
>>> from django.db.models import IntegerField, Sum

>>> Client.objects.aggregate(
    regular=Sum(
        Case(
            When(account_type=Client.REGULAR, then=1),
            output_field=IntegerField()
        )
    ),
    gold=Sum(
        Case(
            When(account_type=Client.GOLD, then=1),
            output_field=IntegerField()
        )
    ),
    platinum=Sum(
        Case(
            When(account_type=Client.PLATINUM, then=1),
            output_field=IntegerField()
        )
    )
)

>>> {'regular': 2, 'gold': 1, 'platinum': 3}
```

So yes, it is possible. Given your example above, it would be along the lines of:

```
from django.db.models import IntegerField, Sum

SomeTable.objects.aggregate(
    price_sum=Sum(
        Case(
            When(other_model__some_field_name='some_value', then='price'),
             default=0,
             output_field=IntegerField()
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: The problem is that I need this query inside an extra tag, i.e. `MyModel.objects.extra(select={my_sum: "SELECT SUM(price) FROM some_table_name ...` so I'm afraid it's not that simple :(

Comment: So `my_sum` is a variable that is passed in, so that when you call `instance.<my_sum's variable name>`, you get the sum for that particular object's instance, and not an overall sum?

E.G.  `my_sum = 'price_sum'` then `instance.price_sum` prints out the annotated price sum.